# What's Request Class (in Kohana) Common Tasks?

Tags: model-view-controller, request, kohana, response

I'm creating PHP framework with MVC architecture and I take ideas from some already finished frameworks like Kohana 3.1. I have seen Request class in lot of other frameworks too. What's it common tasks? Nice explanation would be priceless! ))

Comment: You're building a framework and don't know what a request class does?!

Comment: Funny, huh? xD I will try to read source code if noone can't explain using words. (

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Request class will look for a matching route and load the appropriate controller to handle the request.

Comment: Invalid question, invalid answer :\

Answer (score 3):

It represents the user's HTTP request and launches the appropriate resources in the framework (controller usually). Not a terribly difficult concept.